# How can I show that applying a matrix of rank = r to a linearly-independent set of r vectors, gives again a linearly-independent set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, independence

Let $x_1, ... , x_r$ be an independent set.

I want to show that $A(x_1), ... A(x_2)$ is again an independent set.

Basically, I am studying the rowrank=columnrank proof, namely proof # 2 of it on the Wikipedia page that discusses the rank of linear operators.  But Wiki uses orthogonality, and I don't believe that is necessary -- since the topic of inner-product spaces does not show up until the second-half of most linear alg textbooks.  (And the columnrank = rowrank proof shows up much earlier.

Writing the zero vector in the image space as a linear combination of $x_1,...,x_r$ and using the linearity of A, we get that

$$0 = c_1A(x_1)+..c_rA(xr)$$

$$= A(c_1x_1)+...A(c_rx_r)$$

$$= A(c_1x_1+...+c_rx_r)$$

I need to say that $c_1x_1+...+c_rx_r= 0$, in order to use the independence of $x_1,...,x_r$ but how can I do so without the orthogonality argument?

Thanks,

Comment: What you state in the title of this question isn't usually true. $A$ is required to be a monomorphism for this to happen.

Comment: You are having difficulty proving it because it is not true. Consider some basis of $R^2$ and consider projection as a linear transformation. Now what happens to the basis vectors ?

Comment: In addition the my above comment, simply consider a linear transformation from a higher dimensional space to a lower dimensional space. The map of the basis will not be linearly independent.

Comment: Hi @Abel, if I made the assumption that A is of rank = r, would the statement then be correct?  Thanks,

Comment: I don't think so. If you want to prove that row rank = column rank, you could try showing that both quantities are invariant by multiplication by invertible matrices on either side, and (adding and subtracting rows and columns, i.e. multiplying by appropriate matrices) reduce any matrix to a diagonal one with ones and zeros on the diagonal. The number of ones in that case is easy to see that it's the row rank and the column rank. Alternatively you could show that the row rank is the size of the largest square submatrix with nonzero determinant, just like the column rank.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much @Abel.  I'll stick with Wikipedia's proof and move on then. Have a great night :-)

Comment: Another way to see this is wrong is to take $2r$ orthogonal vectors in a large enough dimensional space. Stack $r$ of them as rows of $A$ and keep the other $r$ as your vectors $x_1,\dots,x_r$. Note that now $Ax_1,\dots,Ax_r$ goes to zero vectors, though all your conditions are met.

Comment: Thanks @dineshdileep; I am guessing that it was crucial to assume that x1, ... , xr form a basis for the row space of A, and also assume that A has row rank = r.  At least that's the beginning of the proof on Wiki, which at first doesn't seem different from the assumptions I made in my own attempt at a proof...